# Probability theory book with examples

Tags: book-recommendation

Hey I am looking for a book about probability theory with as much as possible examples with conditional expectation and filtrations. What do you recommend?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156165/good-books-on-advanced-probabilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following references: 
$1.~~$ "[Probability: Theory and Examples](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf)" by Rick Durrett (Cambridge University Press)
$2.~~$ "[Probability and Statistics](http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/mikevans/jeffrosenthal/book.pdf)" by Michael J. Evans & Jefrey S. Rosenthal 
$3.~~$ "[Probability and Random Processes](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ezt001062/PTmaterials/Grimmett&Stirzaker--Probability%20and%20Random%20Processes%20%20Third%20Ed(2001).pdf)" by  Geoffrey R. Grimmett & David R. Stirzaker (Oxford University Press)
$4.~~$ "Probability Theory, A Comprehensive Course" by  Achim Klenke (Springer)