# Rigorous book on probability theory and statistics

Tags: statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I would like some examples of very rigorous books on probability and statistics. I know there are lots of rigorous books on probability by itself, but I am also looking for a book that makes rigorous the theory behind statistics. From my understanding, there is a difference between probability theory and statistics.

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but [Weighing the Odds](https://www.amazon.com/Weighing-Odds-Course-Probability-Statistics/dp/052100618X) by Williams is very interesting.

Comment: [Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis by John A. Rice](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Statistics-Analysis-Available-Enhanced/dp/0534399428)

Comment: @littleO I think that only holds if $F$ is normal.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Thanks for clarifying that! I should have looked it up. I'm going to just delete my comment that was wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good books on "advanced" probabilities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156165/good-books-on-advanced-probabilities)

Answer (score 0):

[E. T. Jaynes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521592712) is very thoughtful and addresses such matters and properly highlights the role of Bayesian probability and statistics.